# How to make IntelliJ Idea stop warning about certain attributes?

Tags: intellij-idea, getuikit

I'm developing a Vue app using [UI Kit](https://getuikit.com/docs/) which implies using various custom attributes like `uk-grid`, `uk-icon`, `uk-navbar` etc (in Vue single file components' templates). For each one, IntelliJ gives me a warning like

> Warning:(7, 52) Attribute uk-icon is not allowed here

How can I tell IntelliJ not to do this? Googling the warning haven't brought any sane results which makes me think there's no ready-to-use package for this (for this particular UI Kit), so the question is: how to make Idea not to warn about a custom list of attributes? But I'll be glad to be wrong and if there is a better solution, please let me know.

*Update*: like lena has suggested, pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> suggests helpful options, including adding attribute to the list of custom attributes. However, wildcard suggestion didn't work for me: the below screenshot illustrates settings that make `v-localize` attrbute be recognized, but `uk-`-prefixed attribute are still highlighted with warning:

[image: the "Custom HTML tag attributes" field is filled with "uk-*,v-localize"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `uk-*` attributes to **Custom HTML tag attributes** list in **HTML | Unknown HTML tag attribute** inspection; the easiest way to do this is using **Add to custom HTML attributes** quickfix available on `Alt+Enter`:

[image]

Note that IDEA recognizes [Vuikit](https://vuikit.js.org/) components and directives out of the box - did you consider using it instead of pure UIKit?

Comment: Thanks for this and for the tip about Vuikit, we'll consider that one. I succeeded in adding custom attributes on per-attribute basis, but wildcard doesn't seem to work, see the edit of the question

Comment: ah, probably I misunderstood you and there's no support of wildcards, I just have to add each one separately. Let me know if that's not the case, but for now, this is good enough

Comment: wildcards are not supported unfortunately (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19532), you have to add each attribute individually